# CSS how to keep space between two elements if both are displayed and keep right element to the right if the first one is not displayed

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm currently displaying two icons and I kept space between them using flex-box property justify-content and value space-between. The problem is that sometimes only one icon is going to be displayed and I need the V-icon to always stay to the left and the urgent-icon to the right.
I tried to use floats(right/left) or some flex-box properties like justify-self: end or flex-end but it did not work. The urgent-icon goes to the left and it should always stay to the right.
Is is possible to achieve it with flex-box? Where did I make mistake?

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <a class="text-underline flex-wrap w-70" (click)="navigateToDetails($event)">{{request.id}}</a>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-30">
        <img src="assets/v-icon.svg"
             title="Urgent Request" (click)="navigateToDetails($event)"
             [tooltip]="'Link redirects to Vendor Req.: ' + request.id"
             [options]="{'tooltip-class': 'tooltip-style', 'placement': 'top'}">
        <img *ngIf="request?.urgent" height="22" width="22" src="assets/urgent-icon.svg"
             class="float-right">
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: Current result]

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Since hidden elements take up space on the page, I would probably just use `visibility: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the right icon `margin-left:auto`

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em .25em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1em;
}

span:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span></div>

<div><span>2</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spacer between images, with flex: 1 1;

```css
.main{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    display: flex;
}

.spacer{ /* this will expand into all the space left over */
    flex: 1 1;
}

span{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background: rgb(150, 100, 255);
}

.red{
  background: rgb(255, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <span></span>
    <div class="spacer"></div> <!-- Add this between the images -->
    <span class="red"></span>
</div>
<br>
 <div class="main">
    <div class="spacer"></div> 
    <span class="red"></span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="main">
    <span></span>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```